# How to perform SQLite database encryption in iOS Application - Does MobileIron do it?

Tags: sqlite, mobileiron

I would like to include an SQLite database in an iOS application bundle. Does MobleIron encrypt the bundle or does the developer need to encrypt the database?

I am using MobileIron AppConnect for iOS

What can be done to safeguard the database if a hacker steals a device and attempts to read the database?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the bundle and not the source code, you can only use AppConnect wrapper to add MobileIron AppConnect functionality, which doesn't include encryption capabilities.
To encrypt data at rest within the app sandbox, the developer has to include AppConnect SDK in the app. As long as the developer uses NSData Objects there is a correspond AppConnect SecureFile method available in MI AppConnect framework. Well documented in SDK documentation. Please consider that this is only possible for data/database that is created by the app on the MobileIron secured device. It is not possible to encrypt data and include it in your ipa File for distribution.